# how to do substring from back side

Tags: c#

I am trying to put a substring from the back on a string 
"csm15+abc-indiaurban@v2". The substring should start from "@" till the first special character i.e. "-". The special character can also be "+" in some string. so finally after applying the substring from "@" till "-" , i want "csm15+abc".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [`String.LastIndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof(v=vs.110).aspx), particularly where you can specifiy a starting index

Comment: And `String.LastIndexOfAny(new char[] { '-', '+' }, atIndex)` to get the "special character"

Comment: I don't understand your question, you say you want a substring between the last special character (`-` or `+`) and `@`, but that the result should be `csm15+abc`.

Comment: Can you give us a better example?

Comment: [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s = "csm15+abc-indiaurban@v2";
var idx =  s.LastIndexOf('@');
var idx2 = s.Substring(0, idx).LastIndexOfAny(new char[] {'+', '-'});
var tail = s.Substring(0, idx2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var s = "csm15+abc-indiaurban@v2";
    var idx=  s.LastIndexOfAny(new char[] {'@', '+', '-'});
    var tail = s.Substring(idx);
```

Comment: This will return `v2` given the above string.

Comment: Sorry. Too fast with answering.

Comment: I'm still not convinced this does what he wants, but the question is so unclear anyway.

Comment: @WicherVisser - please explain how this code resolves the problem.  Code-only responses are generally considered to be poor quality answers.

Comment: My full answer is pending awaiting a clear example from the OP. See comments on his post.